Glass render is black for some reason and I tried tweaking the light paths on render properties
I'm almost sure that some sort of setting a did before on a different proyect is affecting this one now, but to be honest I don't want to factory reset my settings since I'm scared I mess something up and cannot restore it back.
I even tried moving the bounces since I heard that the mayority of the time that resolves it, but not this time for me.

I was testing with a red cube behind but I cannot even see the white background. The other object on the scene has a different approach of the glass nodes to test it but that one also comes black.
Im new on this forum so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right but here is the file: 

I see you have a JPG in your environment texture for the world... if this is intentional, okay. I do not know how much experienced you are in Blender, I just mention it because usually for better lighting it is recommended to use HDRIs as environment, maybe watch some tutorials on HDRI lighting for more information.

Oh, I actually though I applied the HDRI's correctly, my mistake, I'll definetly will check for some tutorials as you recommend, Thanks for that as well!

First of all, your "Simple Glass" material is totally fine, in the following explanations I used it for both objects (maybe you could set the Roughness to a small value above 0, because real glass is never perfectly smooth, but that's not relevant for the issue). People often say simple glass materials do not look good in Blender and make workarounds, but most of the time it is just the settings that are not good.
The black glass is (mainly) caused by much too low Max Bounces in the Light Paths settings. You have everything at 3, I would recommend at least 16 for Glossy and 32 for Transmission - and for those values to have an effect, the Total has to be set to at least 32 as well.
Your settings:

My minimum recommended settings:

And while this already looks a lot better (do not mind the distorted look on the left glass, I will deal with it later), setting the Glossy to 32 is still improving the result (look especially at the top edge of the right glass). My default settings are usually Total 64, Glossy 32 and Transmission 64, but that's just me. Sure it increases render times (by a bit), but it's a lot more realistic glass.

Now the bottom of the left glass is still black where it meets stands on the ground. This has nothing to do with the bounces, this is due to the fact that you have Caustics disabled. See on the left a slight improvement after enabling Reflective caustics, and then the even better one on the right after enabling Refractive caustics as well (if you want to disable one of them for improving render times, disable the Reflective caustics and leave the Refractive enabled).

The last thing is the weird distortion on the left glass. This is caused by the fact that it is set to Shade Smooth and the smoothing is stretched across the whole area. To get rid of that, go to the Modifiers tab and add a Normals > Smooth by Angle modifier. The glass on the right does not look so distorted but it does not hurt if you give it this modifier as well. Instead of using a modifier you could also right-click on the object and choose Shade Smooth by Angle - but note that this marks edges above the chosen angle threshold as sharp, which might not be what you want if you are eventually changing parts of the glass later.

All in all looking at it here from different viewpoints it seems to me the normals are still stretching quite a bit especially at the top of the right glass, so what I would recommend - which has nothing to do with the glass material itself, but other than opaque materials, due to the inner reflections and refractions, some normal issues with smooth shading might be amplified by the glass material - maybe add some Bevel modifier to the objects and probably a Subdivision Surface modifier, both before the Smooth by Angle modifier.

Thank you so much for your help! I applied what you mentioned and it definetly looks so well now, and the response on the forum was so quick also. Again thank you so much!
